# Why is $\int \limits_{0}^{t} f(s)\,ds$ usually interpreted as the "accumulation" of $f(t)$ in some sense?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was reading a paper which defined a function $c(t)$ as the consumption of some resource at time $t$.  Then, a new function was defined: $C(t) := \displaystyle \int \limits_{0}^{t} c(s)\,ds$, which was named the "cumulative consumption" up to time $t$.

> **Edit** If we had finitely many time points, and you told me to define the cumulative consumption at a specific time, I would think to add the previous consumptions up.  So I am confused as to why we are calling this integral the cumulative consumption if that's not what we are doing -- unless we are?  This is where my confusion lies.

Why do we think about the definite integral in this way?  I understand why $\dfrac{1}{t} \displaystyle \int \limits_{0}^{t} c(s)\,ds$ is called the *average* of $c(t)$ over $[0,t]$, but I don't have a similar argument for why the integral itself can be considered in some sense the sum of $c(t)$ from $0$ to $t$.

Comment: Riemann sums??????

Comment: @Batman Thanks for your comment.  There's no need for the excessive question marks.  Riemann sums are definitely sums, but if the function is positive they represent the area under the function, not exactly the "sum" of the function between $0$ and $t$, so your comment isn't illuminating to me.

Comment: @user46944 Although unnecessary, I think the excessive question marks served more to complete the character threshold than sounding pedantic.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo If that were true, it would make Batman a very lazy commenter (with little regard for how these time saving "tricks" come across in tone).

Comment: Indeed, I am a very lazy commenter.

Answer (score 1):

This is very often the definition of an integral. In particular, one usually defines
$$ \int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim \sum f(c_i) [x_{i+1} - x_i]$$
where $c_i \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]$ and the limit is taken as the widths $|x_{i+1} - x_i| \to 0$.

If $f(x)$ is the consumption per unit time, then the intervals $[x_{i+1} - x_i]$ are durations of time, and each summand $f(c_i) [x_{i+1} - x_i]$ is the (consumption per time) $\times $ (period of time) $=$ (consumption in time period). So in fact it is tremendously natural.

Comment: Your answer is great, but you didn't really clarify on what the unit of time is.  For example, if $f(x)$ is the consumption per *second*, then to figure out the consumption for three seconds, we would calculate $f(x)*3$, right?  But then, since $f(x)$ is variable, I'm not sure what the unit of time would be.  It's not seconds, or milliseconds, etc.

Comment: You didn't clarify what your function was defined as. For instance, if $f(t)$ is the wattage at some time, then a watt is a joule/second and $t$ would most naturally be time in seconds. Or perhaps your function is some other consumption function over some other unit of time. It depends on the function. But the idea is always the same. This is the same idea as how integrating an instantaneous speed (such as meters per second or miles per hour) against the elapsed time (such as seconds or hours, respectively) gives you the distance traversed (in meters or miles, respectively).

Comment: Yeah, but it's still confusing.  For example, if $t$ represents seconds, then as you discretize $[0,t]$ into finer and finer subintervals, you are considering smaller and smaller units of time.  So when we take the "limit" as the interval width goes to $0$, it's not intuitively clear to me how the resulting limit of sums is the "sum" of $f$.  I don't even know if I'm explaining this properly.

Comment: To the second point of your last comment: I never understood intuitively why integrating the instantaneous rate of change against the elapsed time gave you the distance traveled, so I guess I have had this question since taking Calculus all those years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you split [0,t] into discrete intervals and add all midpoints evaluated at c(s), that's a Riemann sum. The integral is when the size of the interval approaches 0.

Comment: It's not a Riemann sum unless you multiply each midpoint by the length of the interval you were considering it over.  That's the main point of my confusion.

Comment: Is there a reason you think you can't do that? That's just the definition of integral. Edit: yeah, I didn't mention the part where you have to multiply by the length of the interval. you wouldn't have to if the length was 1, but otherwise you do.

Comment: Exactly, so when the length is no longer 1 your explanation is no longer adequate.

Comment: I think you're confused between the concepts of length and area. Say, you have a line segment of length k. What is its area? And that's not a well posed question. you always have to take the width into account. And you're asking, "where does the width come from?" You either arbitrarily set a width (riemann sum) or make it as small as possible.